# Setting background color in gvim

Tags: linux, vim, colors, gvim

I use a terminal with white text on black background (I just like it better), so I wrote the following line in my `.vimrc` file:

```
set background=dark
```

However, `gvim` has black on white text. How do I do either of the following:

- Set the background of `gvim` to black
- Check in `.vimrc` if I'm using `gvim`

I tried this: I started up `gvim`, and typed `echo &term`. The answer was "builtin_gui". So I wrote the following into `.vimrc`:

```
if &term == "builtin_gui"
    set background=light
else
    set background=dark
endif
```

Somehow, it didn't work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`set background` does not change the background; it tells `vim` whether your background is dark or bright (light).

You could use your `.gvimrc` file to set colors specific to gvim.  I set my color scheme to slate, desert, or evening because I like light-on-dark color schemes:

```
colorscheme slate
```

Or you could add this to your `.gvimrc` or `.vimrc` to set the colors to white-on-black:

```
highlight Normal guifg=white guibg=black
```

Comment: When I start gvim, does both .vimrc and .gvimrc run?

Comment: Yes. Anything in `.gvimrc` should run after `.vimrc`, so `.gvimrc` preferences will take precedence over `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 3):

I found below settings in .vimrc/.gvimrc are more easy and convenient for dark theme in gvim

```
" Dark mode settings
colors koehler
highlight LineNr guifg=DarkGray
highlight Search guibg='Purple' guifg=#FFFFFF
highlight String guifg=#FF5733
highlight Visual guibg=#000000
highlight Pmenu guifg=#000000 guibg=#808080
```

For gray theme instead of dark

```
colorscheme evening
set bg=light
```